# Why does a Markov chain with one irreductible class has a lower triangular transition matrix?

Tags: markov-chains

Given a Markov chain on an infinite and countable set of states, with one irreductible class that has a finite number of states, why can its transition matrix be put in a lower triangular form ?

$\begin{bmatrix}D & 0\\R & Q\end{bmatrix}$

And then, why is its asymptotic behavior not unique?

I would be very grateful if people could direct me to a good book that discusses the behavior of Markov chains based on the structure of their transition matrix :)

Cheers